# How to Generate SubReport in crystal report with SQL Query?

Tags: sql, vb.net, crystal-reports, subreports

I am Having a  Report Which has to generate from Two different where Clauses.

```
**Condidtion 1**
Select * from Table1 where Name="ABC"

**Condition2**
Select * from Table1 where city="LA"
```

In above mentioned case, the condition two should appear in sub report part 
Please remember the Data is populatinf from same table and in same crystal report

Condition 2 Will be in subreport

Comment: Create a Datasoruce and name the subreport as sub1 or anything paste the following code   `rptdoc.Subreports("sub1").SetDataSource(dv1)` where in above case dv1 is datasource for new criteria as mentioned in condition 2

Answer (score 0):

Create a Datasoruce and name the subreport as sub1 or anything paste the following code

rptdoc.Subreports("sub1").SetDataSource(dv1)